# Customer care video call service with webrtc

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc

I want to implement webrtc in our website to provide customer service.User should be able to call our experts through video call if possible.but when i visited some demo sites, I found out the user has to send a url first and then wait for the other party to visit this url which is not our requirement.we want direct video meetings with 2 people like skype.how can i implement it  any ideas or examples?

Comment: No, any page can be active, it is your signalling servers job to connect different parties. So, you can give a user an id, see what people are available for the call(your support personnel showing "online" with your signalling server) and just exchange the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

Check out OnSIP InstaCall - It's prebuilt for this use case and delivers a video call from your website to your agents (can also deliver custom website visitor data along with the call). You can see it in action on OnSIP's Facebook page > InstaCall Now tab: https://www.facebook.com/onsip/app_888168771195532  -- Login and then see click-to-video-call button. Setting it up requires:

1. Open OnSIP account $49.95/mo (free 30 day trial)
2. Create users
3. Give users (your experts) login information to InstaPhone (free WebRTC-based phone)
4. Group your users if you like (e.g. Sales Team, Support Team)
5. Create button script with call destination settings (directly to user or to call group)
6. Place button script on webpage

InstaPhone also offers an 'instant call link' for your experts to give out to customers. If you wanted to get more custom with the front end, you can use the open source library SIP.js.